# How to change backgroundColor checkmark in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, checkmark

I am using Checkmark in Tableview

I want to change my backgroundColor Checkmark but i couldn't

I dont know how do it

Can you please help me, thanks

[image: unselect]
[image: select]

Comment: the _real_ question is, how do you change the background colour of your cell currently?

Comment: cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray in willDisplay but didn't work add checkmark

Comment: you may need to use `cell.contentView.backgroundColor` instead – however, you use the `lightGray` colour and your cell still seems having a `darkGray` background colour... why is it so?

Comment: because  i used cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray in didselect No problem if I do checkmark unselected,the background becomes white when I add

Answer (score 0):

Change the `UITableViewCell`'s tint color and this will change the checkmark's color as well

`cell.tintColor = .red`

Answer (score 0):

After selecting your cell in table view you need to change selection in inspector as shown in below image to change color during selection

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
cell.accessoryView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: <0>, y: <0>, width: <20>, height: <20>))
cell.accessoryView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```